# py2neo merge is returning None

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have the following code:

```
for t in set(tags):
    new_tag = Node('Tag', name=t)
    tag = graph.merge(new_tag, 'Tag', 'name')
    rel = Relationship(tag, 'TAGGED', post)
    graph.create(rel)
```

The problem is that `graph.merge()` is returning `None`, but [documentation](https://py2neo.org/v4/database.html#py2neo.database.Transaction.merge) says it would crate a new node if no matches are found.

This is the error I get when `graph.create(rel)` is executed:

```
 File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/FlaskrGraphProject/FlaskrGraphVenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/internal/operations.py", line 134, in <genexpr>
    for labels, nodes in _node_create_dict(n for n in subgraph.nodes if n.graph is None).items():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'graph'
```

Answer (score 0):

commit after merging. And then create the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use:

```
tag = graph.merge(new_tag)
```